# How to make query where three model has relation with each other in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

For example, I has three models:

`Model A:`

```
`field = CharField`
```

`Model B:`

```
 `fk = Model A`
```

`Model C:`

```
`fk = Model B`
```

**Now I want the get the values of Model C by the reference from Model A, How can I achieve this?
Model B can have multiple records of Model A.
Now I want to get all the results from Model C against those records.**

So more specific by using ID in Model A, I want to get all the results from Model C.

Answer (score 0):

```py
C.objects.filter(fkB__fkA = id_in_model_A)
```

To access variables of other forign keys use double under score

documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships